# Receive "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address" on Google Colab

Tags: python, sockets, google-colaboratory

I received a strange error when i am using google colab and ask for some hints to config colab. Below is the code for reference:

```
import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=10)
smtp.connect('alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com')
```

In personal labtop, i will receive this:

```
(220, b'mx.google.com ESMTP q2si18528340oiv.98 - gsmtp')
```

However, in colab, i received this:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    714             if source_address:
    715                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 716             sock.connect(sa)
    717             # Break explicitly a reference cycle
    718             err = None

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

May i know the root clause of it? and what should i do in colab config to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to : `cat /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Add:
`c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = 'https://colab.research.google.com'`

Restart Notebook